# Firebase has no exported member promise

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

It was working fine without any issues. I tried to update the "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1" to latest and then rolled back the version after that i am getting this error. Can somebody please let me know if there is any version mismatch ? Thank you.

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.1.3",
"@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
"@angular/core": "4.1.3",
"@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
"@angular/http": "4.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
"@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^4.4.2",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
"@ionic-native/device": "^4.6.0",
"@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.6.0",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.4.2",
"@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.6.0",
"@ionic-native/photo-library": "^4.4.2",
"@ionic-native/printer": "^4.6.0",
"@ionic-native/push": "^4.6.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"angular2-signaturepad": "^2.8.0",
"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
"chart.js": "^2.7.1",
"cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
"cordova-ios": "^4.5.4",
"cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.6.0",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^3.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
"cordova-plugin-fcm": "^2.1.2",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.2",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^3.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-photo-library": "^2.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
"firebase": "^4.6.2",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^7.0.0",
"phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.2.2",
"rxjs": "5.4.0",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.2.7",
"@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.3",
"@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
"ionic": "3.7.0",
"typescript": "2.3.4"
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded my firebase version to 3.9.* it worked.